# Laravel Socket.io,Redis event is broadcasting but not showing on client side

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io

In my `laravel.log` i can see the event is broadcasting on the channel i.e.

```
[2018-08-30 13:41:27] local.INFO: Broadcasting [App\Events\NewRating] on channels [rating] with payload:
{
    "music": {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "1535368873_admin.mp3",
        "path": "public\/music\/1535368873_admin.mp3",
        "rating": 53,
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2018-08-27 11:21:13",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-27 11:21:13",
        "is_last_played": 1,
        "is_now_playing": 0,
        "location_id": 1
    },
    "socket": null
}
```

As of i know i have done everything according to requirement.my `redis` server is running.`laravel-echo-server` is running and it is joining my channel i.e.

```
[18:41:24] - VX9bkHqs-QHRv3MvAAAC joined channel: rating
```

This is where i am subscribing to the channel and listening to the event

```
window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        beforeMount: function () {
        alert("asdas");
        this.joinPublicChatChannel();
        },

        methods: {
        joinPublicChatChannel: function () {
            Echo.channel('rating').listen('App\\Events\\NewRating', (event) => {
                console.log("Event fired!"); //This doesnt work
            });
            }
        }
});
```

and this is my event class

```
class NewRating implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{ 
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $music;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Music $music)
    {
        $this->music=$music;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('rating');
    }
}
```

and this is my env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_restaurant
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=
```

Dont know the reason behind :/

**UPDATE**

Just cleared all the caches, Now im getting this in `laravel-echo-server` console

```
Channel: rating
Event: App\Events\NewRating
Channel: rating
Event: App\Events\NewRating
Channel: rating
Event: App\Events\NewRating
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in your event file :

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'NewRating';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, I got this running :). just cleared the caches and in

```
Echo.channel('rating').listen('App\\Events\\NewRating', (event) => {
            console.log("Event fired!"); //This doesnt work
        });
```

I used `NewRating` instead of `App\\Events\\NewRating`